# How to show array value one by one in javascript in innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard forloop:</p>
<label id="lab"/>
<button onclick="myfunc()">ok</button>

<script>
    function myfunc() {
        fru = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        for (i = 0; i < fru.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = fru[i];
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the label when I click a button. I have stored 5 values in array. How do I show these array values *one by one* when clicking on a button?

If I click once, it will show the first label and on my second click it will show the second label.

Comment: so what will happen to the previous element? Will it be still shown or it will over written?

Comment: it will display the last value directly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a global variable as counter to store number of clicks and supply this counter value as index to array to display the elements. This will show value one by one as you click

```
<script>
var counter=0;
function myfunc(){
   fru = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

   if(counter == fru.length)
     counter = 0; //reset index once end of array is reached 
   document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = fru[counter];
   counter++;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: its not working for will.it will show directly second value

Comment: check edit .. increment of counter variable should be after displaying

Comment: check now.. changed condition from greater than to ==

Comment: what will happen inside the if condition the counter=0 means

Comment: it is resetting the index of array stored in counter variable back to zero once end of array is reached

Comment: i did't click it.i don't know the functionality of stack overflow.you have me a best solution only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a varibale outside the `function`. Maybe the `array` or a `counter variable`. This is up to you. One way could be to use `splice` to shrink the `array` on every `click` and output the just the first value.

```js
var fru = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myfunc() {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML += fru.splice(0, 1);
}
```

```html
<label id="lab" />
<button onclick="myfunc()">ok</button>
```

Comment: What? Where? It don't does! @KalaiPrakash

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard forloop:</p>
<label id="lab"></label>

<button onclick="myfunc()">ok</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var counter=0;
function myfunc() {
  fru = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var _innerString = '';
  if(fru.length>counter){
  _innerString = fru[counter]+('<br>');
  counter++;
  }else{
  counter=0;
  alert("Array Reset");
  }

 document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML =_innerString;
}
```